# Ansible : You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible

i m using centos-ansible and i m facing the issue as below.

FYI, when **i m using ubuntu -ansible** **i did'nt get the below warnings and i can able to proceed to the same playbook.** But in centos i m failing with same yml file.

```
[root@jenkins-server ~]# ansible-playbook deploy-ws.yml
```

PLAY [Dev] ************************************************************
/usr/lib64/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.
  _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [10.0.2.56]

TASK [unarchiving zip files] ***************************************************
fatal: [10.0.2.56]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "python isn't present on the system.  Unable to compute checksum"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/deploy-ws.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.0.2.56                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

```
[root@jenkins-server ~]# python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  1 2015, 18:18:03)
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

i followed the below links:

https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/28335/you-should-rebuild-using-libgmp-5-to-avoid-timing-attack-vulnerability-_warnnot-using-mpz_powm_sec-you-should-rebuild-using-libgmp-5-to-avoid-timing/

http://devnumbertwo.com/you-should-rebuild-using-libgmp-5/

but same error prevails.

my yml code:

```
---
 - hosts: Dev
   user: www-upload
   vars:
    Doc_base: /var/www
    Env: dev
    Release: MM-MM-1
    Symlink_var: /data/assets/var
    Symlink_media: /data/assets/media
    Local_xml: app/etc/local.xml
    CACHE_TYPE: "{{cache_type}}"
   tasks:

    - name: unarchiving zip files
      unarchive: src=/tmp/{{Release}}.tar.gz dest=/var/www/{{Env}}/deployments/ owner=www group=www
```

Comment: What's the result of `which python` when logged in (the one that displayed version 2.7.9)?

Comment: `[root@jenkins-server ~]# which python
/usr/bin/python `

Answer (score -2):

It's just a warning message,looks ugly.
You can comment the two lines that cause the warning.

For example:

```
$ vi /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py
```

```python
#if _fastmath is not None and not _fastmath.HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC:
#    _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)
```